Issue when using Prometheus scrape_config_files parameter
The following is a sanitized version of the job configuration for scraping the endpoint of a Sybase monitoring instance.
- job_name: sybase-job
  basic_auth:
    username: "user"
    password: "password"
  honor_timestamps: true
  scheme: https
  scrape_interval: 30s
  scrape_timeout: 30s
  metrics_path: "/prometheus/metrics?tls=false&port=13603&target=10.10.10.10:12311&entity=NPASEX.SYB_UK-DEV-01&entity_type=SYBASE"
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  follow_redirects: true
  static_configs:
    - targets: ["10.10.10.10:12311"]

When defined in the prometheus configuration file, it's picked up without issue when invoking a config reload. However, if defined in a separate file and referenced in the main config file using scrape_config_files parameter, it fails with an unmarshal error
scrape_config_files:
  - /prom_config/dir/sybase/*.yml

Full error:
May 14 13:11:49 promhost1 prometheus[1033]: ts=2024-05-14T12:11:49.650Z caller=main.go:1255 level=error msg="Failed to apply configuration" err="\"/prom_config/dir/sybase/npasex.syb_ukdev-01.yml\": yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 1: cannot unmarshal !!seq into config.ScrapeConfigs"

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Please see above. Scrape config has been defined in both methods with the expectation that it should work consistently.
